# How to properly add a chrome-like material in cycles to a thin object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

i was trying to put a chrome-like material in a curve that i'm doing, because it needs to somehow 'shine' on the borders, like a detailed curve/tube, something like this: [image]

Is this possible to do with a thin object like this? i need to zoom it in the animation, so that's why i need it to be detailed on the material...oh and also, it should stay with black background so it will not reflect anything at all.

Thank you in regard.

Comment: Use the antisopotry shader and the glossy shader. The rest is lighting. Notice that material questions are not necessarily strictly on-topic for this site.

Comment: Could you clarify the `it should stay with black background so it will not reflect anything at all.` part?

Comment: It will not and can't reflect anything since the background is fully dark/black

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Random shading tips

---

### Different world colors for background and reflections

Below is an example of using a different color for the background than for the reflections. In addition to colors, you can of course also use, for example, an HDR image for reflections and radial gradient for camera, or other kind of combinations.

[image: Different world colors for background and reflections]

---

### Procedural reflections

For reflective materials something is needed to be reflected. Common and nice looking method is to use an HDR image. However, sometimes a simple gradient node can look nice in reflections. You can sort of 'paint' your reflections with it in real-time, which is cool :)

[image: Gradient node reflections]

---

### Keep the scale

When using procedural shaders, it's important to reset the scale of the object if it has been scaled:

[image: Keep the scale]

---

### Don't skimp on detail

When modeling an object, it's good to test how the light will bounce off the surface. For example, adding some double-beveling easily leads to nicely highlighted rims for some metallic objects:

[image: Don't skimp on detail]

---

### My test

[image: My test]

[**dented_chrome.blend**](http://files.manujarvinen.com/dented_chrome.blend)

Answer (score 6):

Just add a *glossy shader* to the pipes and use some oblong planes with an *emission shader* for lighting. Give them various colours and strengths. You can also experiment with the glossy shader's *roughness* value to see what you like.
[image]

Set the *background shader* to black as you like.
[image]

If you want a transparent background in the image file, check the *transparent* box in *render settings* (just make sure you save as a file type that supports an alpha channel like .png).
[image]

Here's the result.
[image]

Comment: What's the point of the color ramp with no input?  And mixing two background shaders with different shades of grey?  You could just have one shader and adjust the color's value.

Comment: You are right. I could have just one shader. But I'm used to using the colorramp. You can't forbid me ;). I can replace the picture according to your suggestion if you like. May be simplier and clearer.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply use a *glossy* shader with a roughness value of around 0.1.  To get the specular highlights as they are in the picture I would position a plane with an emission shader behind the camera facing directly at the pipes.

To get the black background just go to the *world* panel of the *properties* view and set the background shader to be pure black.

Comment: and a bluish tint to the glossy.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest either a glossy shader as above or a [convolution/environment map](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/Environment) for more precise control with very low overhead.

Comment: Good advice! Could you expand your question to help people follow what you mean?