# How can I add more reflections to my glass material?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to reach a render like the one on the image below. It's a prism as you can see, and I already made the elements, but the reflections aren't the same.

Maybe it's the material, but I do not know. I already tried changing the object's position and lighting, but it didn't help. So I think it could be the material

[image: blender with prism object]

Comment: Could you post a .blend file for testing?

Comment: Better lighting and add a bevel to the prism maybe. Working on a file . . .

Comment: your prism looks like there's an empty space inside, your ref doesn't. play with IOR. and plug nodes outputs to same colored inputs.

Comment: the rainbow ray could be nicer with some transparency and using a color ramp to smoth colors transitions. You could also add a ground plane.

Comment: I gave some [tips](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23092/how-to-properly-add-a-chrome-like-material-in-cycles-to-a-thin-object/24293#24293) on reflections and shading a little time ago. Perhaps they could help you?

Comment: I'm not even sure if that is an actual 3D-generated model, or if it was mocked up in a 2D program . . . Try to get a photo-realistic reference if you can unless that is the exact effect you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several basic issues with your scene, the first one I want to address is your Prism. It is not detailed enough, so there is not a large enough number of angles to bounce the light. Add a *Bevel* modifier, and a *Subdivision* modifier to your mesh, and then fix your material to be just a *Glass BSDF* node with an IOR of 1.44-1.90 (depends on personal preference, this is the realistic range of glass).

**The prism is the most important part of the scene**, so take your time. This should be something like what you end up with:

[image: Prism Wire]

Now model the light beams. I have the white one coming in, and curving slightly out the other side (artistic license, not technically correct). I also have them overlapping, so that in the material I can fade from one beam into the next. Like so:

[image: Prism beam]

Now work on the materials, I set mine up like this:

**White**

[image: White beam nodes]

**Spectrum**

[image: Spectrum Nodes]

Notice that you may need to change mapping values for both materials. Also, I unwrapped the Spectrum mesh and am using the UV map to map the *Color Ramp* just to give some more control.

**Render Result**

[image: Prism Render]

Now that the basic scene is setup, it is just a case of tweaking lighting and the prism until you have the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! a last question, can you make that 'rainbow' with transparent/diffuse borders?

Comment: You can, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your material setup is wrong. On first glance you are feeding shader output to glass node color input.

Leave only 1 glass node connected to Shader output, delete the rest.

If you then need more reflections you can mix in a Glossy shader with Fresnel node.

Comment: That helped a lot! thank you! but what about the 'curved reflections' inside the Triangle/Piramid?

Comment: i think it's the spot being refracted through the prism

Comment: @beavoru either the prism in reference pic doesnt have flat surfaces or the ribbons themselves are curved. Then you should get also a curved reflection.

Comment: Thank you, i'm already adding more geometry, but still i need to fix the interior parts of the geometry :)